# How to create new scene from .sks file and programmatically change its size

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skscene

Right now I load my GameScene like this

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

 if bool {
    // Change size to CGSize(a, b)
 } else {
    // Change size to CGSize(x, y)
 }
 view.allowsTransparency = true
 scene.backgroundColor = .clear
 view.presentScene(scene)
}
```

However, depending on a certain `bool` I want to be able to change the initial size of the GameScene. I know this can be done using `let scene = GameScene(size: size)` but that means I can't use the .sks file for the GameScene which I have most stuff on.

How can I variably change the initial size of the GameScene  while still using the .sks file?

P.S. `scene.size = CGSize(a, b)` does not seem to change anything

Comment: why do you want to do this?  Scene.size = CGSize does change the size,  but because of how scalemode works, you may not notice any differences.  If I had an understanding of your purpse, I can better help explain a solution for you.

Comment: right, essentially OP just has to use `.scalemode`

Comment: OP, are u using an `SKView` to hold the `SKScene` ?